# 301 redirect ASP.NET IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a site, that has aliases:

site1.com

site2.com

site3.com

But they are all the same site.

I need the rules for asp.net, that will allow site3.com & site2.com to redirect  to **www.site1.com** with status 301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the URL Rewrite module in IIS to redirect these requests.  Something like this might work (though this may need tweaking)...

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="site?.com" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.site1.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.site1.com/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

EDIT - Forgot to include the redirectType attribute

Comment: Xeka needs a 301 redirect (probably for SEO reasons) and this isn't it:)

Comment: @rciq - Would you care to add a little more detail?  I admit that I forgot to include the redirectType, which I just added.  When I use this, IIS sends me a 301.

Comment: Additionally, this is added to the web.config, which may make it easier for @Xeka to implement in his environment.

Comment: You are right! I just suggested Xeka to give your solution a try:)

Answer (score 0):

I think a better option is to set these things in IIS. In IIS7 you can create a site (or even a virtual dir) for the unwanted domains, then in the 'HTTP redirect' section you can set the destination and your desired HTTP status code.

If for some reason you cannot do this via IIS try searching SO for coded solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+301+redirect

Comment: I use the hosting, but there is no access to IIS. I can edit only asp scripts :(

Comment: Then you should give FlyingDeveloper's solution a try (he's now added the redirect type). Go for a coded solution only as a matter of last resort.